# Can I send auto generated email via Cloud Function and GSuite GMail API?

Tags: gmail, google-cloud-functions, google-workspace

I have GSuite organisation and Google Cloud Project. I need to send auto-generated email from f.e auto@myorg.com on google cloud invocation. Is it possible?

There are lots of examples how to send email via gmail from cloud function. But how can I use my organisation email as a sender source.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#creatinganaccount).

You'll need to [delegate domain-wide authority to a service account](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) that's bound to your GCP project and enable the appropriate scopes to send email via the gmail api.

Once you have your service account properly configured you can then leverage the [google api node.js client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-nodejs-client) with your service account credentials in your cloud function to send emails on behalf of any user within your organization.